# PHP login form to direct user onto new page

Tags: php, html, if-statement, input, xhtml

I've created a login form on HTML that asks for a specific username + password. (User = hello, pass = bye)

I want my PHP form to check if the user input is correct (Hello & Bye), and if so, direct the user to a page called "**next.html**"

Here is my **login.html** form

```html
<html>

        <h1> <font color="red">Log In To Add Entry!</font></h1>

<form name="myForm" action="login.php" method="post">

<fieldset >
<legend>Login</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

 <label for='username' >UserName*:</label>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" /> 

<br> <label for='password' >Password*:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />

<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

</fieldset>
</form>
</html>
```

My **login.php** :

```html
<?php

function Login()
{
    if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    
    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    
    if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    session_start();
    
    $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;
    
    return true;


    
}

?>
```

and my **next.html** page, where I want the user to go if the user + password are correct:

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

        <title>Entry page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> <font color="red">Add an entry to Joe's Blog!</font></h1>




</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

use header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); to redirect users. Change your code to this:

```
<?php

    function Login()
    {
        if(empty($_POST['username']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
            return false;
        }

        if(empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
            return false;
        }

        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password))
        {
            return false;
        }

        session_start();

        $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;
        header("Location: next.html");

        return true;

}

?>
```

Comment: How do I make sure it verifies that "Hello" is the user and "Bye" is the password?

Comment: didn't you do that in `$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password);` function ?

Comment: here is the function (forgot to include it) : From here, how do I finish the if-statement to check the username/password?                                                    
function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
    {
        if ($username == hello)

Comment: I don't think you posted the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

In **login.php** just add above;

```
if( Login() ) {
     header("Location: next.html"); exit();
}
```

If you just want to use that one login info then **replace:**

```
if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password))
```

**With:**

```
if( $username == "hello"  && $password == "bye" )
```

Comment: or just add `header("Location: next.html");` instead of return true?

Comment: How do I make sure it verifies that "Hello" is the user and "Bye" is the password?

Comment: I assumed it's checked by - if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)) ??

Comment: Sorry-- just a bit confused with how you answered. So should my new code look like this?   `if( $username == "hello"  && $password == "bye" )

        {
                header("Location: next.html"); exit();    
        }
`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php

    function Login() {

    if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);


    if ('hello' == $username && 'bye' == $password) {

        session_start();

        $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;
        header("Location: next.html");
        return true;

    }
}

?>
```